# ASP.NET MVC5 controller action method parameter null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to modify the property names posted to a controller action from within a `@Html.EditorFor`?

I have a view that both displays a list of objects and a form that should allow a user to create one. I only want to post back the new object values upon creation rather than the entire viewmodel if possible.

My ViewModel structure for the view looks like this:

```
public class GenericIndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<GenericListViewModel> ExistingObjects { get; set; }
    public GenericCreateViewModel NewObject { get; set;
}

public class GenericCreateViewModel
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

In the view I'm looping through `ExistingObjects` to display all existing objects, and underneath I'm creating a form with `@Html.BeginForm("Index", "GenericController", FormMethod.Post)` and inside I have the appropriate `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.NewObject.PropertyA)`. View snippet below:

```
@model Namespace.Models.Generic.GenericIndexViewModel
...
@if (Model.ExistingObjects.Any())
{
    // Display list of objects
}
...
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "GenericController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="field-holder">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewObject.PropertyA)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NewObject.PropertyA)
    </div>

    <div class="field-holder">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewObject.PropertyA)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NewObject.PropertyA)
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" name="command" />
    </div>
}
```

The action method signature is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(GenericCreateViewModel model) { ... }
```

When I submit the form it successfully hits the action method although `model` parameter is `null`.

When I inspect the post data I can see that the properties are being prefixed with `NewObject`:

```
NewObject.PropertyA=test1&NewObject.PropertyB=test2
```

How do I either prevent the prefix, or get the action method to recognise the prefixed properties as arguments?

Comment: What is your @model in your View?

Comment: please show the necessary relevant code of view

Comment: Added view snippet as requested.

Comment: `public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "NewObject ")]GenericCreateViewModel model)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please add your comment as an answer as I believe this more accurately resolves the specific question asked.

Comment: @ChrisPickford, Decided to dupe it instead (that answer contains both options)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your editors to

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.NewObject.PropertyA)
```

And change your Post action to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(GenericIndexViewModel model) { ... }
```

and then access `model.NewObject` to get the required `GenericCreateViewModel`.

Or you can try it with:

```
<div class="field-holder">
    <label>PropertyA</label>
    <input type="text" name="PropertyA" />
</div>

<div class="field-holder">
    <label>PropertyB</label>
    <input type="text" name="PropertyB" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="command" />
</div>
```

and keep receiving `GenericCreateViewModel` object in your POST method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(GenericCreateViewModel model) { ... }
```

This is just one way to achieve the desired results.

Comment: Won't this post back the entire `GenericIndexViewModel` including all the `ExistingObjects ` data?

Comment: Tested and no it doesn't, only properties inside the `BeginForm` get posted. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default form behavior will post full model back to your controller so the easy way to fix this is to change your parameter in post Index method to `GenericIndexViewModel`.

If you want to preserve c# method as is you need to override the way data is formatted and make the post request yourself in `onsubmit` event.